# PowerPoint Bullets Macro

Tags: macros, powerpoint, bullet-span

I would like to create a Macro that when I select a text box in Powerpoint, automatic spacing after the bullet will be size 9 arial. Also the bullets will always be square and red.

Can anybody guide me on how to write macro code for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can be achieved without code. Edit the styles on the slide master and apply the desired formatting. Then use that style in the slide.